# Different web contents for the same page

Tags: java, html, url

I am trying to get response of a webpage using Java and write it in a html file for future references in my local.

Many websites having changed contents day by day. For example, in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page, page is showing different contents everyday.

I got response from Wikipedia home page and save it in html, yesterday it was same as wiki home page.

But today, the wiki page turns something different. My html page is as it was yesterday.

How to check that response is different. What would be added in database while I am getting response first time, and what I need to check while call the same url later .

Here is my code,

```
URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("root:pass".getBytes());
String encoding = new String(encodedBytes);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
try {
    fWriter = new FileWriter(new File("f:\\new.html"));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String s = line.toString();
        writer.write(s);    
    }               
    writer.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Try using your browser page inspector to see whats send to the remote server, look at the headers "If-modifed-since" and "If-etag-matches"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using both answers provided by Cyril and Shree29.

First I am checking "Last modified" header and save it in my reference. If it is null then I am calculating hash value and save it.

Thanks Cyril and Shree29.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use the value contained in the "last-mofidied" header in the response from the server. Parsing this into a nice object would allow for simple date comparisons, letting you check if you should re-scrape.

compare site you last rendered date with the date which will get from request headers

```
site_modified_date = request.headers["Last-Modified"];
```

and if there is difference in between them then retrive and load new content to page

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a hash function (check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) to compute the hash value of the website body.
This will always work, even if the Last-Modified header is absent.
You can use the library jsoup (http://jsoup.org/) to retrieve the body text:

```
String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";

Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String bodyText = document.body().text();
String hash = computHash(bodyText);
// save url, hash, document.html()

// next time you retrieve the website:
Document newDocument = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String newBodyText = newDocument.body().text();
String newHash = computHash(newBodyText);

// load existing hash by URL
// hash = loadHash(url);
if (!newHash.equals(hash)) {
    //website has changed
}
```